# Razor DisplayFor() Does Not Iterate Over Collection (but EditorFor() Does!)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My (incorrect?) understanding is that a call to `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeCollection)` should automatically iterate over the collection and call my Display Template for the elements in `SomeCollection`. What I'm seeing, however, is an exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Abc.Services.Crm.Dtos.CrmPersonDto+ViewModelDataClass+UserRoleSelected]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Abc.Services.Crm.Dtos.CrmPersonDto+ViewModelDataClass+UserRoleSelected'.

As you can see, the model being passed to my Display Template is the entire `List` of items, not the individual element.

As an aside, if I call the *Editor* Template, I *do* seem to get the automatic iteration, it's only with the `DisplayFor()` (and Display Template) that I get the exception. When I manually call `@foreach()` on the collection, my Display Template is called just fine.

Here is my Display Template (please do not comment on the VM class structure. I know it needs to be fixed):

```
@model CrmPersonDto.ViewModelDataClass.UserRoleSelected

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsTrue)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsTrue, Model.TitleText)<br/>
```

Now here is my model declaration in my View, followed by the call to `DisplayFor()`:

```
@model Abc.Services.Crm.Dtos.CrmPersonDto
   ... more stuff ...
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserRolesSelected, "UserRoleSelected") // causes exception!
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the 2nd parameter of your `DisplayFor()`. When you add the `templateName`, your are telling the method to pass the model (a `List<UserRoleSelected>`) to that template (which accepts only a single instance of `UserRoleSelected`), hence the error.

Without the `templateName`, the method iterates each item in the collection and passes each instance to the template to generate the html.

Your code should be just

```
@model Abc.Services.Crm.Dtos.CrmPersonDto
... more stuff ...
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserRolesSelected)
```

Note this assumes that the `UserRoleSelected.cshtml` partial is in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` (or `/Views/YourControllerName/DisplayTemplates`) folder.

Comment: If that's the case, then why does it work perfectly well if I use EditorFor()?

Comment: It does not work using `EditorFor(m => m.UserRolesSelected, "UserRoleSelected")` (assuming your `EditorTemplate` for `UserRoleSelected` has `@model UserRoleSelected`). You will get exactly the same error. I am not sure why you are claiming that it works.